# Identifier 'methodname' is not defined in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am a newbie in ionic, Just created a blank app and trying to add an action to a button. I am getting the following error – ‘Identifier ‘buttonClicked’ is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member’. Please let me know what I am doing wrong here?

[Sample code](https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/ionicframework/original/3X/2/5/259aac4543de0df9b19136b62cd6f03e4511d912.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create the corresponding method in your home.page.ts file. In the Screenshot i see, that you have opened the home.module.ts file, but your method has to be in the home.page.ts file.

Comment: Yes that's a thing I added in module.ts and struggling. Thank you for catching it

Answer (score 0):

Your `HTML` call of the `ion-button` component is correct.

Your code snapshot does not show the `TypeScript (.ts)` part though.
You should have the corresponding method in there. Something like:

```
onClick() {
   console.log("button clicked ok");
}
```